# Run Length Encoding the code

Tags: python, python-3.x, run-length-encoding

I am very new to coding and picked python as my first coding language. I am working on a exercise called Run Length Encoding. After some searching I found solution but I am having hard time understanding the code. Can someone break this code and explain in simple words. Thank You.

```
string = 'WWWWWWWWWWWWBWWWWWWWWWWWWBBBWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWB'
x=''.join(['{}{}'.format(k, sum(1 for _ in g)) for k, g in groupby(string)])
```

Comment: Have you (a) not read the docs for [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), (b) read them but not understood them, or (c) understood them but don't understand how to break the rest down? What the answer focuses on will be different in each case.

Comment: Your code is incomplete.  `groupby` is not a standard function.  It must be imported from a package; the exact behaviour will depend on which package it is imported from.

Comment: @AJNeufeld I think it's pretty obvious he's using `itertools.groupby` here. While the question would be _better_ if he made that clear, I don't think it's unanswerable as is.

Comment: @abarnert I did read the docs for groupby. I just don't understand whats going on in this line. There are "for" functions within in Join. I am just unable to comprehend this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to do is to break down the expression into smaller ones:

```
bits = ['{}{}'.format(k, sum(1 for _ in g)) for k, g in groupby(string)]
x=''.join(bits)
```

The second one is easy: we have some list of bits, each of which is a string, and we just join them up into one big string.

The first one is a list comprehension. Every list comprehension can be rewritten as a `for` statement around an `append`, so let's do that:

```
bits = []
for k, g in groupby(string):
    bits.append('{}{}'.format(k, sum(1 for _ in g)))
```

---

The [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) part may seem tricky if you've never seen `groupby` before, but if you just call it separately, it should be pretty obvious:

```
for k, g in groupby(string):
    print(k, list(g))
```

This gives you:

```
W ['W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W']
B ['B']
W ['W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W']
B ['B', 'B', 'B']
W ['W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W']
B ['B']
```

In other words, each group `g` is a run of equal elements, and `k` is just the thing they're all equal to.

---

Now let's break down the inner statement:

```
bits.append('{}{}'.format(k, sum(1 for _ in g)))
```

into parts:

```
count = sum(1 for _ in g)
bit = '{}{}'.format(k, count)
bits.append(bit)
```

The last two lines are hopefully obvious. So, that just leaves us with the first one.

---

We're calling `sum` on a generator expression. Generator expressions are just like list comprehensions but lazy, and we don't care about the laziness here, so we can break it down the same way we did above:

```
things = []
for _ in g:
    things.append(1)
count = sum(things)
```

So now it should be obvious what `sum(1 for _ in g)` does: it's just the number of things in `g`. In fact, it's just like calling `len(g)`, except that it works for arbitrary iterables, including lazy iterators, not just sequences.

This is the idiomatic way to count possibly-lazy iterables—but we could have replaced it (at the cost of a bit of performance) with:

```
count = len(list(g))
```

---

So, putting it all back together:

- Use `groupby` to convert the string into a bunch of groups, each of which is the same character repeated over and over.
- For each one:

  - Count the length of that group.
  - Make a string like `'W12'` using the key `'W'` and the fact that the group of `W`s has 12 members.
  - Append that to a list.
- Take that list of `['W12', 'B1', 'W12', 'B3', 'W24', 'B1']` and join it into a string `'W12B1W12B3W24B1'`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider `s = 'WWWWWWWWWWWWBWWWWWWWWWWWWBBBWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWB'`.
Your code is equivalent to:

```
x=''.join(['{}{}'.format(k, len(list(g))) for k, g in groupby(s)])
```

```
x=''.join([str(k) + str(len(list(g))) for k, g in groupby(s)])
```

```
l=[]
for k, g in groupby(s):
    l.append(str(k) + str(len(list(g))))

x= ""
for s in l:
    x += s
```

From the documentation, " [groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) makes an iterator that returns consecutive keys and groups from the iterable".

It's easier to understand it with an example.

```
print(*[(k,list(g)) for k, g in groupby(s)], sep="\n")
```

outputs:

```
('W', ['W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W'])
('B', ['B'])
('W', ['W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W'])
('B', ['B', 'B', 'B'])
('W', ['W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W'])
('B', ['B'])
```

In practice each element in the iterator returned by groupby is a `char c` with an iterator to the list of all the consecutive `chars c`.

In your code you first create a list with all the pairs (c, number of consecutive times c appears):

```
x1 = ['{}{}'.format(k, len(list(g))) for k, g in groupby(s)]
# ['W12', 'B1', 'W12', 'B3', 'W24', 'B1']
```

then all the elements in the list are joined together to create a single string

```
x2 = "".join(x1)
# W12B1W12B3W24B1
```